# Regular Expression for extract left value match with right

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with a Regular Expression issues, I want to extract only "abc" from below specified string and looking for regular expression all of that.

`1-var abc`

`2-function (abc)`

`3-xyz.abc`

`4-function abc()`

please suggest so I will be much grateful to you, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by extract ? You want to match the second token ?

Comment: Do you want to find all function names, parameter lists, fields, and variable names?

Comment: Can we see your attempt? Surely you've made one?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: If you try to *"find all function names, parameter lists, fields, and variable names"* then the best solution would be to use a parser. There are very good JS parsers written in JS.

Comment: I'm afraid your problem is underspecified. Do you want the last sequence of letter characters in the string?

Comment: @HamZa Is that still the policy ? I couldn't understand the last blogs on that point and there doesn't seem to be any reference now...

Comment: @dystroy it's no longer officially a close reason, but it's still in the FAQ and it still applies. The existing ones should theoretically cover all cases.

Comment: @dystroy I'm quite tired of the new closevote-reasons. A change after another. IMO it's counter productive and as you can see the queue has rised from under the 100K to ~108K. You could say I'm now following a bit of my own policy, if the user doesn't show any efforts I close vote it with a custom reason.

Comment: @HamZa the closevote queue is rising no matter what. The new close reasons have zero effects on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to match variable names, parameters to functions, member access, and function names; you can easily split those into separate cases then match against all of them:

```
var rVariableName      = /^var\s+(\w+)/;
var rFunctionParam     = /function\s+\w+\s+\((\w+)/;
var rMemberDereference = /\w+\.(\w+)/;
var rFunctionName      = /function\s+(\w+)/;
```

(These are hopefully accurate, I didn't test them)

Comment: There exist long file extensions, FYI. Among them, `.html`, `.java` and `.class` are fairly common, `.jpeg` less so, and `.graphml[z]` exists as well.

Comment: True, I was just doing an example case. I would hope they could expand to more cases from here.

Comment: Also, I  believe they meant property access in javascript, not a file extension.

Comment: Getting too used to Perl, but of course that makes much more sense. It will definitely the 1/4 that wasn't like the other.

Comment: (of course, `{1,3}` makes no sense in case of property access ;-)